# PHP - How to sort an array by appearance of variable character

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
$array = array("no_spaces","one space","two 2 spaces");
```

I want to sort/order the array by how often a specific character appears. In this case " "

so in return I would get the following array

```
    [0]=>
    string(12) "two 2 spaces"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "one space"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "no_spaces"
```

I've been looking through the php.net manual and haven't found any commands that can do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `usort` in combination with a method to search for the character (or pattern)

```
$array = array("no_spaces","one space","no_space","two 2 spaces", "two 1spaces", "two 3 3 spaces");
usort( $array, "charSort" );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $array );
echo '</pre>';

function charSort($a, $b) {
    preg_match_all( '/ /', $a, $aa );
    preg_match_all( '/ /', $b, $bb );
    if( count( $aa[0] ) == count( $bb[0] ) )
        return 0;
    return (count( $aa[0] ) < count( $bb[0] )) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) together with [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to sort your array, e.g.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return substr_count($b, " ") - substr_count($a, " ");
});
```

Comment: Why is this answer voted down? It worked great for me. Is it a bad practice or anything?

Comment: "Is it a bad practice or anything?" it is not. ppl might think `usort` needs to return -1, 0 or 1, but that is not a requirement. As long as it returns an integer, it wont act weird. Personally i like this more than my answer...